# wpf load resource from another folder/namespace

Tags: wpf, xaml, namespaces

How can I load a resource e.g. a style resource from another folder in the same project? Any ideas?
My [directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlEX6.png) looks like this and I want to use the ButtonStyles.xaml within the ButtonTest.xaml. In the design mode ,before starting the application. Using the resource in the App.xaml works perfectly during runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your custom style in a ResourceDictionary in the folder you want - 
in my example the file is /Resources/Themes/Button.xaml. Give the style a key:

```
<Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    // define your style, for example
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
<Style>
```

In case you wish to add multiple style files, it is good to merge your ResourceDictionaries,
 for example into a file called Generic.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/PROJECT_NAME;component/Resources/Themes/Button.xaml"/>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/PROJECT_NAME;component/[path and file name]"/>
    // add all your resourcedictionaries 
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

where you want to use the styles, add the merged ResourceDictionary as a Resource. For example in a UserControl,
add it like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <inf:DesignTimeResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/PROJECT_NAME;component/Resources/Themes/Generic.xaml"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Then when you add your button you can use the style as a dynamic resource using the key you gave it.

```
<Button Style="{DynamicResource MyButtonStyle}"/>
```

Make sure to change all the names to match your project and file names.